# jquery carousel auto scroll with text and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm using the jquery carousel and I have the image auto rotating here ( http://jsbin.com/unoce/2), so the issue I'm having is the content on the left is not AUTO rotating "with" the image and the arrow selection is not either. It only works when I click the content on the left and then the image on the right along with the arrow move appropriately together.

Can someone provide support so I may get the text and the arrow to "auto" rotate with the image?

This code below would only rotate the image and nothing else...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#features").jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    auto:2,
    wrap: 'both',
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null
  });
});
```

***Here's a demo and you can edit this demo too:
http://jsbin.com/unoce/2***

Thank you,

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://jsbin.com/unoce/7/edit

- You're using an old version of jQuery (1.3.2). The current is 1.4.2, so I switched it in the jsBin to use Google's hosted version of jQuery.
- This wasn't part of the issue, but I consolidated some code. You had several calls to `$(document).ready()`. This isn't bad, but it isn't necessary either. I consolidated the code into one `ready()` call.
- You were assigning 2 click handlers. Again, this is fine, but unnecessary. I put the code from both into the callback for the `initCallback` property.
- The `initCallback` only gets called once, at the beginning. That is why the `current` class wasn't getting updated when it would auto update.

jCarousel has a lot of other callback options. One is called `itemVisibleInCallback`. It actually takes an object that can take two callbacks:

```
itemVisibleInCallback: {
      // This one is called before new item is displayed
  onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemVisibleBefore,

      // This one is called after new item is displayed
  onAfterAnimation: mycarousel_itemVisibleAfter
}
```

That is where I took care of removing and adding the `current` class.

Those callbacks can have four parameters: carousel, item, idx, state

I had to use the `idx` parameter to refer to the proper item under `#features-nav` because the `item` parameter seemed to refer to the item being scrolled.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Patrick. You solved it. I'm baffled though. What's causing the last slider to hang like that?

Comment: patrick. i figured out the answer to my question just now. the width in the style sheet needed to be 600 not 630. sorry to ask an extra trivial question. Thank you so much for your help just now...